# Convert a PowerShell date to a JavaScript date (Unix time)

Tags: javascript, powershell, datetime, data-conversion

Am trying to obsfuscate the API key from zscaler

https://help.zscaler.com/zia/api-getting-started, but they have no documentation for powershell.

I did the conversion from javascript to powershell : Here the function for your information

```
Function Obfuscate {

PARAM (

[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="apiKey")][String] $key,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="Timestamp")]$timestamp

)

$apiKey=""

$high=$Timestamp.substring($timestamp.length -6)

$low=$high -shr 1

$low=$low.ToString()

While ($low.length -lt 6) {$low="0"+$low}

For ($i=0;$i -lt $high.length; $i++) {

$apiKey+=$key.substring($high.substring($i,1) -shr 0,1)

}

For ($i=0;$i -lt $low.length; $i++) {

$apiKey+=$key.substring(($low.substring($i,1) -shr 0)+2,1)

}

return $apiKey

}
```

It remains only one problem , that is very annoying :

Date.now() (for the timestamp variable) in javascript/java/python and son return a 13 digit number (1519984360183) (which is supposed to be time in second since 1970/01/01 00:00:00:00)

The similar function in powershell :

```
$timestamp=([Math]::Floor([decimal](Get-Date(Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()-uformat "%s"))).tostring()
```

or

```
$timestamp = (Get-Date -UFormat %s)
```

Return a 15 digits number

Running the script to send a post request with a 15 digits timestamp give an error as Zscaler server doesn’t recognize the obfuscated api key.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

Note: The answer below corrects your own approach, but note that **in Windows PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell (Core) a much simpler solution is available**:

```sh
# PSv5.1+
$timestamp = [datetimeoffset]::Now.ToUnixTimeMilliSeconds()
```

<sup>*Note*: The above, which directly returns *whole seconds* (as a `[long]` instance) implicitly performs (half-away-from-zero) *rounding* on the fractional seconds part to return an integer representation, which differs from your own *truncation* approach.</sup>

---

**Fixing your attempt**:

- **`Get-Date -UFormat %s`** returns a (stringified) value in **(fractional) *seconds***,
- whereas **JavaScript** uses **(integral) *milliseconds***.

Both are representations of [Unix (epoch) time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), but in different units (and with different number types).

Therefore, **you need to multiply by `1000` and convert the result to an integer** (simply cast the result to `[string]` or apply `.ToString()` if you ultimately need a string representation):

```sh
$timestamp = [Math]::Floor(
  1000.0 * [double]::Parse((Get-Date ([datetime]::UtcNow) -UFormat %s))
)
```

- `([datetime]::UtcNow)` returns the current point in time as a UTC timestamp, which is necessary, because Unix time is expressed in UTC; it is the shorter (and faster) equivalent of `(Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()`.

  - Note: To get the correct result in *Windows PowerShell* you *must* provide an *UTC* date as input (a `[datetime]` instance whose `.Kind` value is `Utc`). This is no longer required in *PowerShell (Core) v7+*.
- `[double]::Parse()` parses `Get-Date`'s string output into a `[double]` instance, using culture-*sensitive* parsing (whereas a `[double]` cast would be culture-*invariant* and would only accept `.` as the decimal mark).

  - Note that in *PowerShell (Core) v7+* `Get-Date -UFormat %s` now more sensibly returns a string representing an *integer*, i.e. *whole seconds*.
- `[Math]:Floor()` then truncates that double (drops the fractional part); the result is a `[double]`, but without decimal places. if you need an actual integer *type*, cast to `[long]`.